# BeautifulSoup passing regex as argument

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this html:

```
title="Keeper: Michal Buchalik" class="pos_text">Buchalik</a></span>                
                                            <span class="pos_text pos3_l_5">
```

I try to match `Buchalik`.

I came up with this code:

```
for gk in soup.find_all(re.compile("pos_text pos3_l_\d{1,2}")):
    print gk.previous_element.previous_element,
```

It does not match anything and there must be a problem with the regex, as when I type in a certain number in place of `\d{1,2}` it works just fine.

Comment: I found one obvious mistake in my regex, this part of code was missing `class_=`, though it is still not giving me expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's python, you need to use r for "raw text" or escape the '\' character:

```
re.compile(r"pos_text pos3_l_\d{1,2}")

OR

re.compile("pos_text pos3_l_\\d{1,2}")
```

See if it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but escaping is not needed in the above. Notice that in the original HTML page, there is no backslash character.

Comment: Yes but your regex uses the \d (a digit) construct. So, it's not the text that needs escaping but rather the regex itself. Just try it?

Comment: It seems that the problem is not the regex then - because re.compile("pos_text pos3_l_\d{1,2}").split(<your string>) seems to act as expected.